# Salesforce Commerce Cloud : Unable to upload cartridges from vs code facing 403 Forbidden error

Tags: commerce-cloud, demandware, b2c

I'm uploading cartridges from vs code in the staging environment and I'm getting the following error.

```
Current active version is: b33_20200522_stg
Start uploading cartridges
Cleanup code version...
[app_custom_xyzcorp] Deleting remote zip (if any)
[app_custom_xyzcorp] Zipping
[app_custom_xyzbrands] Deleting remote zip (if any)
[app_custom_xyzbrands] Zipping
[app_custom_xyzcorp] Sending zip to remote
[app_custom_xyzbrands] Sending zip to remote
Error: Error: Forbidden 

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <title>403 - Access denied</title>
    <link rel="STYLESHEET" type="text/css" href="/waroot/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Access denied</h1>
    <img src="/waroot/system_arrow.gif" width="21" height="21" alt="" border="0">
    <p class="system_info">
        Access to the specified resource has been forbidden.
    </p>
    <hr>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm having the role of "Admin" for the user with all access. Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Is the password for your BM account correctly set in your `dw.json` file ? Do you need a [certificate to upload code to staging](https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC2/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/content/b2c_commerce/topics/site_development/b2c_creating_and_using_certificates_for_code_deployment.html)? if yes do you have set this up correctly

Comment: Yes BM account is correct as I'm able to make the connection, but only while uploading the cartridges facing the above issue.
I haven't tried with the certification.

Answer (score 0):

For uploading code to Staging instances, you must use a 2-Factor Authentication Certificate. This certificate is supplied by Salesforce Commerce Cloud Support as an attachment to the Support Case that was opened when the realm was created. You use this cert along with a valid User authentication (which it sounds like you have) to authenticate, and then you can upload the cartridges/code.

2-factor auth is supported by the `sfcc-ci` ([Github](https://github.com/SalesforceCommerceCloud/sfcc-ci) / [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sfcc-ci)) CLI tool.